# Get information from table based in conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having some trouble trying to figure out a way to get some information from a table based in some conditions.

What I am trying to do: Case the CATEGORY column is in A, B, C or D the I would like to get the date from the DATEX column. If the Category is in E, F I would like to get the date from the DATEY column:

```
SELECT
    COLUMNX
FROM
    TABLE A
WHERE
    A.CONDITION1 = A.CONDITION2 AND
    (CASE
    WHEN A.CATEGORY IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') THEN
        A.DATEX = (SELECT ...)
    WHEN A.CATEGORY IN ('E', 'F') THEN
        A.DATEY = (SELECT ...)
    END)
```

But this isn't working, I am getting sintax errors. Any help will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Case` statement you can `AND/OR` logic to simulate `IF-Else` in `Where` clause. Try this.

```
SELECT COLUMNX
FROM   TABLE A
WHERE  A.CONDITION1 = A.CONDITION2
       AND ( A.CATEGORY IN ( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' )
             AND A.DATEX = (SELECT ..) )
        OR ( A.CATEGORY IN ( 'E', 'F' )
             AND A.DATEY = (SELECT 1..) )
```